# Inquiring about the subject

Tags: grammar, pronouns, questions

I've heard of such constructions:

> I've just seen John.
>    **John whom?**

when you don't know who John is.

Can other pronouns be used in a similar manner?

> I've put it there.
>   **There where?**

or should it be *Where - there?* instead?

Answer (score 2):

This does not really answer your question but your first premise, I believe is incorrect. It should be John who? Because it is the same as saying "Who is John?"
In the second case, I would choose "where...there?"

Answer (score 1):

It's an **[elepsis](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ellipsis)** of:

> *(You've just seen)* John who?

**[Elepsis](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ellipsis)** from OLD:

> NOUN
>
> 1 The omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.

Note: *whom* has no place in this composition.